# How do they do this? (Android, scrolling)

Tags: android

I recently downloaded the Weather Channel app and I'm intrigued by the way the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom scrolls under a curved arch.

Here's a link to a screenshot:  http://dailydroidapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/The-weather-channel-app.jpg

It includes a little bit of pop-up text that covers the top of the arch but moves side-to-side with the scrolling.    The scrolling moves in a straight line; it doesn't curve with the arch, but the peak of the arch with its little highlighted glow helps to emphasize the current selection.

I'd like to learn how to do this -  any suggestions about what they are doing?   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a tabcontroller for the horizontal scroll, and a PNG (the arch) with transparency placed on top of that (a higher z-index), gradually going from opaque background to transparency?